# Cordova use different cordova Version

Tags: android, cordova

I have a reale simpel question.
I am using Cordova for my Projekt in Android.

I have the CLI version 4.0.0 on my PC.
If create a Projekt the CLI tool is creating it with the version
3.6.3 (var CORDOVA_JS_BUILD_LABEL = '3.6.3';).

But i want to use the version 3.2.0.
This is how i Build the Projekt:

```
*$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build*
```

Is there a way to tell the CLI to use the version 3.2.0?

Sorry about my bad English.

Regards isi

Answer (score 1):

You must install multiple version of cordova.
http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1379